# How do I fix this JBoss EJB client authentication issue?

Tags: java, jboss, ejb

I have an EJB deployed under JBoss (we're moving a project to it from Weblogic), I can get an EJBHome reference to the EJB via a JNDI lookup.

The login-config.xml application-policy contains several login modules (I don't know if these are ANDs or ORs?) - org.jboss.security.spi.BaseCertLoginModule, LdapLoginModule, RoleMappingLoginModule and ClientLoginModule.

When my client code tries to invoke the create method via reflection, calling invoke, I get an InvocationException which wraps an AccessException, which wraps a final exception of javax.security.auth.login.FailedLoginException: Password Incorrect/Password Required at org.jboss.security.auth.spi.UsernamePasswordLoginModule.login(UsernamePasswordLoginModule.java:213)....

Am I missing some client code to use BaseCertLoginModule, or one of the others in the login-config.xml, instead of UsernamePasswordLoginModule?

Thanks in advance, any suggestions appreciated, apologies for not posting the entire stacktrace but it's on a secured network without internet access.

Comment: What kind of authentication do you want to be using?

Comment: Whatever makes it compatible with what's defined in the login-config.xml. Which I guess is either BaseCertLoginModule, LdapLoginModule, RoleMappingLoginModule or ClientLoginModule. If I had to pick one of those I'd say BaseCertLoginModule, I know we were using certificates with weblogic.

Comment: It's so frustrating when you're searching for answers and your own question keeps coming up in the search results!